# Need to track the date/time a report is printed

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Each time a specific report is printed, I would like to capture the date, store that date, and then display that date in a control on the report entitled "Last Printed On:".  If it has not been printed before, I would like to display "First print".

Not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store this data in a table within the database.

table Layout:

id | reportname | firstprint | lastprint

instructions:

On report.load() query the table to see if the report has a record for first print.  If it does not have a record set that field with the current date.  If it does have a first print record, update the last print with the current date.  Then on report.current() you can use if statement to see if a query has a lastprint record for that report.  If it does then set the text of an unbounded label to "Last Printed On: " & the date.  If it does not have a date in the lastprint then you can change the unbounded label to "First Print: " & date.

If you need help with the vba PM me and I'll assist.

Comment: Hey Obie, I am not sure how to PM on SO?

Comment: Sorry there is not PM, I do not know what I was thinking. The most we can do is either email or start a chat on here.

Comment: Email is fine with me.  What is your address please?  Or do you want mine?

Comment: Forgive me, but when I click on account it is not there.  Only thing there is:

website  workingonit
location United States
age  27
visits member for 7 days
seen 1 hour ago
stats profile views 9

Comment: Hoping to hear back from you.  You can email me at the email address in my profile if you wish to do that instead.

Comment: Can we try this again Obie?

Comment: @prayingmantes check out my profile and I have an email address in there you can contact me.